# Laravel getCountForPagination() issues when query has 'having' clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The `getCountForPagination()` function from laravel crashes when the queries have a `HAVING` clause in them.
Basically what it happens is that function removes everything from the select and adds a `COUNT(*)` and the `HAVING` clause does not see the aliases anymore.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Can you post your query or code of the query builder. if you have debbugBar installed, can you post the queries and your intended query.